# How to unit test a @JmsListener method

Tags: spring-boot, jms, spring-jms, message-listener

I am trying to do unit testign on my method which is also a @JmsListener

```
 @JmsListener(destination = "queue")
public void processMessage(String content){
   //doSomething();
}
```

But the problem is : to run my test I need to start my application and load my context etc ... (Spring boot application). But once my application run I connect to the queue and start processing real message.

In my unit test how can I avoid reading real message ?

thanks for your help

Comment: If you just wnat to unit test you don't have to start the context, right? You method anyhow only receives a String and returns nothing so from that perspective it should be fine.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, actually I need to start a context because in my method I'm using injected service provided by spring

Comment: Do you want a unit test or an integration test? For a unit test, create an instance of your class, mock the dependencies and fire of your test.

Comment: You're rigth it's more an intergation testing than  a unit one